# Swift adding multiple stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString on one String?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, binary

Hello i would like to create a app that changes characters into binary code and i was wondering if there is a way to add multiple stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString on one String or if i should take another approach to this "Problem".
Here is what i have so far

```
func textToBinary(theString: String) -> String {
    return theString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("a",
        withString: "01100001")
}

textArea.text = textToBinary(lettersCombined)

// lettersCombined is the string that i want to turn into BinaryCode.
```

Comment: Yikes. That's a really inadvisable way to go. What you want to do is create an `NSData` object from the string using ASCII string encoding and format the resulting bytes into binary.

Comment: String encodings are a really deep topic. I would strongly recommend you read [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to get a better understanding of what strings actually are before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you. I am really new to Swift and IOS.

Comment: Do you know any great NSData tutorials? :)

Comment: What result do you expect for the strings "ä", "€", "" or "" ?

Comment: That is a great question :D

Comment: I just found a website that translates (&#128516;) into 001001100010001100110001001100100011100000110101001100010011011000111011 http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func textToBinary(theString : String, radix : Int = 2) -> String {
    var result = ""
    for c in theString.unicodeScalars {
        result += String(c.value, radix: radix) + " "
    }

    return result
}

println(textToBinary("a"))
println(textToBinary("abc", radix: 10))
println(textToBinary("€20", radix: 16))
println(textToBinary(""))
```

(The last one is a smiley face but somehow my browser can't display it).

**Edit:** if you want to pad your strings to 8-character long, try this:

```
let str = "00000000" + String(c.value, radix: radix)
result += str.substringFromIndex(advance(str.startIndex, str.characters.count - 8)) + " "
```

The first line adds eight `0` the left of your string. The second line takes the last 8 characters from the padded string.

Comment: Oh and one more question :) When i look up the binary alphabet "a" is equal to "01100001" but on the textToBinary function "a" is equal to "1100001", do you know why that is the case? and btw thank you so much :)

Comment: That's due to padding, like `5 = 05`. Binary numbers are customarily padded with 0 so their length is 8 character long. You can add the padding as needed

Comment: How would I go about adding extra zeros to the result depending on if the the letter, number, special character is equal to 8 digits in binary. So fx the number 0 is 110000 but i want it to be 00110000. So that a character in binary always will be 8 digits on letters, numbers, special characters etc

Comment: Thank you so much, you're awesome btw i couldn't get      str.characters.count to work but it would work if i changed it to        count(str)

Comment: Sorry to mention that's Swift 2.0. `count(str)` is correct for Swift 1.2